# systemd-boot: /vmlinuz-linux not found

Tags: arch-linux, initramfs, systemd-boot

I installed the systemd boot loader. But while booting it shows `/vmlinuz-linux` and `initramfs-linux.img` not found.
How can I fix this?
My directory structure is as follows;

[image]
Output of `lsblk`:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a boot partition? If so, is the picture above in your boot or root partition?

Comment: Please add  the output of `fdisk -l`

Comment: I added the output of `lsblk` as it also shoes the mount point.

Comment: Indexable text rather than hard-to-read pictures, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your /boot and /boot/efi are on separate partitions. The UEFI firmware expects to fine the missing files on the EFI System Partition, which is mounted on /boot/efi, but they are now in /boot.

Move the files to /boot/efi, or better yet merge the two file systems so that the EFI System Partition is mounted on /boot.